# Parametric curve on sphere with specific tangent vector at point

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric, spheres

I consider the unit sphere with parametrization $\sigma: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given as

$$\sigma(u,v) = (\cos(u)\cos(v), \cos(u)\sin(v), \sin(u))$$

Now consider $w = (1,1,-1)$ which belongs to the tangent space at $p = (\pi/4,0)$, that is $w \in T_p \sigma(U)$.

My question is: How do I find a curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ on $\sigma(U)$ such that $\gamma(t_0) = \sigma(p)$ for som $t_0 \in I$ and such that $w$ is a tangent vector at this point, i.e. $\gamma'(t_0) = w$?

I tried several things, among this I tried to consider the equation for the tangent space and unit sphere and tried to derive some relations which could lead me to a candidate curve but was unsuccesful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is just something you were working on for recreation. The problem is that $w$'s coordinates are computed in the standard frame $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ whereas vectors in $T_p \sigma(U)$ are computed in terms of,

$$\{ e^1:=\sigma_u(p), e^2:=\sigma_v(p),e^3:= \sigma_u(p) \times \sigma_v(p)\}$$

Hence, if you want $\gamma \in \sigma(U)$ i.e not just tangent at $\sigma(p)$ then $\gamma$ is on the sphere for a neighborhood of $\sigma(p)$ and so,

$$w=\gamma'(t_0) = \sum_{j=1}^2 \bigg(\gamma'(t_0) \cdot e^j(p)\bigg) \ e^j(p)$$

If the above equation can we solved then there must exists an $\alpha$ such that $(\sigma \circ \alpha)'(p) = w$ . Thus you can take $\gamma(t) = (\sigma \circ \alpha)(t)$. If you allow that $\gamma$ just be tangent at $\sigma(p)$ then take $\gamma(t) =  \sigma(p) + tw$. If you want an explicit formula for the curve then take,

$$\gamma(t) =  \frac{\sigma(p) + wt}{\|\sigma(p) + wt\|}$$

In terms of how to compute $\alpha$, observe that $w$ in terms of $T_{\sigma(p)} S^2$ is a two dimensional vector $(a,b) = (\gamma'(t_0) \cdot e^1(p), \gamma'(t_0) e^2(p))$ and so to move in the direction $w$ from $\sigma(p)$ means to travel along the image of the line $p+t(a,b)$ and this is $\alpha(t)$, why? Well by chain rule,

$$(\sigma \circ \alpha)'(0) = Df(p) \cdot \alpha'(0) =  \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_u(p) & \sigma_v(p) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = w$$

Hence, you can also take $\gamma(t) = (\sigma \circ \alpha)(t)$.

Comment: In the future, rather than delete an answer and post a second one, why not edit and then undelete the first?

Comment: @AlexM. In the past, solutions have been overlooked due to downvotes on things that I was in the process of editing. It never seems like a post can be revived after a downvote, this is the reason why I chose to just post a new answer. Not to be rude, but why does it matter?

Comment: I need $\gamma$ to be on the sphere, i.e. $\gamma(I) \subset \sigma(U)$, therefore a tangent curve wont suffice. The derived equation from the chainrule makes sense, but I still fail to see how such $\alpha$ is determined?

Comment: I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Fabric: Check the edit I've made.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Yes, I am familiar with this issue. To be honest, I too "downvote and run" - but only extremely poor posts. Notice, though, that this was not the case with your other post on this page: it had received no downvote. In general, it is a matter of keeping things orderly on Math.SE (you may have noticed that if you want to add another answer to a question that you have already answered, Math.SE first asks you if this is really what you mean, and recommends editing the other answer instead).

Comment: @AlexM. You are right. In the future I will just try not to be so quick to post.

Comment: @Fabric: Also, the previous comments are there to explain why you can't just choose any $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and expect this to be the case. I didn't know whether this problem was taken from a book or was something you made up.

Comment: Thanks! Before I accept this answer (since the curve fulfills all the assumptions): I tried to make a plot in space and the resulting curve appears parabolic. I would expect a circle placed the proper plane to fulfill the assumptions (apparent when you visualize it), but is such a parametrization 'hard to obtain'?

Comment: What I should of said was, $w$ in terms of $T_{\sigma (p)}S^2$ is a two dimensional vector $w^*$ and so the curve parametrized by $\gamma$ is the the image of the line $p+tw^*$ say $(I_{w^*})$ and so if you are are $\sigma(p)$ then you travel on the coordinate-line $I_{w^*}$. This means that in the above if you let $w^*=(w \cdot e^1, w \cdot e^2) = (a,b)$ then $\alpha(t) = p+t(a,b)$. Hence, you can also take $\gamma(t) = (\sigma \circ \alpha)(t)$.